# Why does this method without fail produce a "malloc_error_break" every run?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, debugging, runtime-error, out-of-memory

I have a method that I use to retrieve data from a plist that looks like this:

[image]

The method itself is this:

```
//'path' is of the form "beach.color.green" (for example)
-(NSString *)elementWithPath: (NSString *)path {

    //'self.target' is the path to the plist
    NSDictionary *currentData = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:self.target];

    //This is the number of nested layers that the desired data lies in.
    NSUInteger numberOfLayers = [[path componentsSeparatedByString:@"."] count];

    for(NSUInteger i = 0; i < numberOfLayers; i++) {

        NSString *pathComponentInCurrentLayer = [path componentsSeparatedByString:@"."][i];

        //If the data we're currently searching through is a dictionary...
        if([[currentData objectForKey:pathComponentInCurrentLayer] isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])

            //Narrow our search by making that dictionary the dictionary to search through
            currentData = [currentData objectForKey:pathComponentInCurrentLayer];

        //It's not a dictionary, so it has to be the desired data...
        else

            //So we return it
            return [currentData objectForKey:pathComponentInCurrentLayer];
    }

    return nil;
}
```

I know the method works fine because I stepped through it with breakpoints and verified that it returned the proper output. The thing is, every time I run my project (in which this method is called many, many times), I get the following error:

> PSIslandTerrainGenerator(29202,0x1eb3a28) malloc: *** mmap(size=2097152) failed (error code=12)
>
> *** error: can't allocate region
>   *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
>   PSIslandTerrainGenerator(29202,0x1eb3a28) malloc: *** mmap(size=2097152) failed (error code=12)
>
> *** error: can't allocate region
>   *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
>   PSIslandTerrainGenerator(29202,0x1eb3a28) malloc: *** mmap(size=2097152) failed (error code=12)
>
> *** error: can't allocate region
>   *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
>   PSIslandTerrainGenerator(29202,0x1eb3a28) malloc: *** mmap(size=2097152) failed (error code=12)
>
> *** error: can't allocate region
>   *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
>   PSIslandTerrainGenerator(29202,0x1eb3a28) malloc: *** mmap(size=2097152) failed (error code=12)
>
> *** error: can't allocate region
>   *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
>   2013-08-26 19:01:15.644 PSIslandTerrainGenerator[29202:a0b] beach.upper_elevation_threshold
>   PSIslandTerrainGenerator(29202,0x1eb3a28) malloc: *** mmap(size=2097152) failed (error code=12)
>
> *** error: can't allocate region
>   *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
>   2013-08-26 19:01:15.647 PSIslandTerrainGenerator[29202:a0b] low_grass.upper_elevation_threshold
>   PSIslandTerrainGenerator(29202,0x1eb3a28) malloc: *** mmap(size=2097152) failed (error code=12)
>
> *** error: can't allocate region
>   *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

I went into Instruments and analyzed the app, and it showed that whenever it crashes the app is using upwards of 3 gigabytes of memory. So I'm guessing that something in this method fails to be released every time it is run, but can't pinpoint exactly what.

Comment: Did you "set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug"?

Comment: @CarlNorum - I wasn't sure exactly where the "malloc_error_break" was, so I didn't set the breakpoint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating a lot of autoreleased objects without draining the autorelease pool. Try using

```
@autoreleasepool {
    // Code that creates autoreleased objects.
}
```

somewhere around the call of `elementWithPath:`. See also [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html).

Comment: Wow! I surrounded the method body with `@autoreleasepool` and memory consumption went from 3 gigabytes with a runtime error every run to under 30 megabytes and no error. Thanks a lot man.